# Run a separate PHP file not related to wordpress?

Tags: php, htaccess

WordPress is installed in the root `public_html` directory. E.g.,

- `public_html/index.php`
- `public_html/wp-config.php`
- `public_html/wp-admin/`

Now I want to run a totally separate PHP file in the same directory. E.g.,

- `public_html/mystuff.php`

How do I run it without WordPress thinking it's part of it?

Comment: You should be able to just visit `/mystuff.php` does that not work? If not, we'd need to know your server setup, e.g. htaccess/nginx config. It may be better to just integrate it into WP via a page template or REST endpoint

Comment: It depends on how separate is this file from your wordpress environment? 

Does this page need to have the same header, footer, or other elements as your wordpress theme? Does it need to obtain any data (users, post content) from the wordpress database?

Comment: @TomJNowell It doesn't. Apparently, it loads WP and shows 404 page. This is just basic Apache server setup.

Comment: @Will. Nope, it's totally not related to WP.